# How to change backgroundColor of a TouchableOpacity created dynamically from array?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I would like to change the backgroundColor and BorderColor of the TouchableOpacity. I know that I can use state to change TouchableOpacity BGColor onPress, but the TouchableOpacitys are created dynamically from a arrayList and I would like to change only the backgroundColor and BorderCorlor of pressed touchableOpacity.

There's my code that create the buttons:

```
 var sizeOptions = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < product.Items[0].Items.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j <  product.Items[0].Items[i].SKUOptions.length; j++) {
     if (product.Items[0].Items[i].SKUOptions[j].Alias == 'Tamanho') {
       var sizeTitle = product.Items[0].Items[i].SKUOptions[j].Title;
       sizeOptions.push(
          <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft:20, height:40, width:40, borderRadius:1, borderWidth:1, borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor:'#000', backgroundColor:'#fff'}} key = {i} onPress={() => this.selectSize(sizeTitle)}>
            <Text style={[{marginTop:10, width:40, height:40, textAlign: 'center'}]}> {sizeTitle} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     )
     }
   }
 }

return (
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}} horizontal={true} style={{marginTop:15, marginLeft: 15}}>
  { sizeOptions }
  </ScrollView>
);
```

This code already works to show the created buttons, I only need to change the colors on press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` object can have a property called `touchableOpacityIndexPressed` which is initialized with `-1` at the beginning.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { touchableOpacityIndexPressed: -1 }
  ...
}
```

When the touchable is pushed to the array, you can to the following:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft:20, height:40, width:40, borderRadius:1, borderWidth:1, borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: this.state.touchableOpacityIndexPressed === (i + j) ? 'red' : '#000', backgroundColor: this.state.touchableOpacityIndexPressed === (i + j) ? 'blue' :'#fff'}} key = {i} onPress={() => this.selectSize(sizeTitle, (i + j)}>
```

Make sure you set the correct state in `selectSize` method for `touchableOpacityIndexPressed` property, in my example I have set it to `(i + j)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate class component for the TouchablOpacity and implement onPress logic there, then in your array use the new created component like this :

```
 var sizeOptions = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < product.Items[0].Items.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j <  product.Items[0].Items[i].SKUOptions.length; j++) {
     if (product.Items[0].Items[i].SKUOptions[j].Alias == 'Tamanho') {
       var sizeTitle = product.Items[0].Items[i].SKUOptions[j].Title;
       sizeOptions.push(
          <NewComponent textToDispaly = {sizeTitle}/>
     )
     }
   }
 }
```